# Mirror Binary Search Tree using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

Looking for some help while practicing Binary Search Trees. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong in my code, as it seems to follow the generic recursion format. Possibly something related to either the temp Node or the return statement? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
public static Node < Integer > mirror(Node < Integer > root) {

    if (root == null)
        return null;
    else {

        mirror(root.left);
        mirror(root.right);

        Node temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;

        return root;

    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming you are searching for something you need to incorporate some `if statement`.  You then keep traversing the tree until the if evaluates to`true`, then you return the value up the chain.  And your tree needs to be sorted for this to work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems you do not allocate memory for the nodes that will belong to the mirrored tree. Note that the instruction

```
Node temp;
```

does not allocate in the heap, but in the stack. When the function returns, this memory is freed and whatever you have stored there won't make sense.

Second, it seems you do not have very clear the traversal pattern and I think that because of the line

```
root.right = temp;
```

poses an kind of asymmetry.

This is a way (in C++ pseudo-code), among others, for getting a mirrored binary tree that uses a preorder pattern:

```
Node * mirror(Node * root)
{
  if root == NULL
    return NULL;

  Node * mirror_root = new Node;
  mirror_root->left = mirror(root->right); // here is where the mirroring happens
  mirror_root->right = mirror(root->left);

  return mirror_root;
}
```

You could try to do the same thing allocating the nodes in postorder or inorder.